# Dropping observations in SAS by conditions that depend on a group variable and sequence of years

Tags: sql, sas

From a **SAS** data set with variables `id` that identifies people and `year` consisting of years from 2000-2010, I want to create a new data set by dropping those individuals who are not observed in the original data set at least for three **consecutive** years.

Here is what the original data set looks like:

```
id year 
1  2002
1  2003
1  2004
1  2005
1  2006
2  2000
2  2002
2  2003
2  2005
2  2007
2  2009
2  2010
3  2000
3  2002
3  2003
3  2004
3  2007
3  2009
3  2010
```

A person is not necessarily observed in each of the 11 years. In terms of this the above data set, I want to drop observations for which `id = 2`.

Comment: Why would you drop ID 2.  It has four consecutive years(2002, 2003, 2004, and 2005)?

Comment: I made a mistake writing the example data. I will correct that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/997ade/5/0) shows how to determine which `id`'s have records with three consecutive years:

```
PROC SQL;
  SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID
  FROM MyTable t1
  INNER JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.year = t2.year + 1 
  INNER JOIN MyTable t3 ON t2.id = t3.id AND t2.year = t3.year + 1;
QUIT;
```

To get all the data use [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/997ade/9/0) :

```
PROC SQL;
  SELECT * 
  FROM MyTable 
  WHERE ID IN 
  (
    SELECT t1.ID
    FROM MyTable t1
    INNER JOIN MyTable t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.year = t2.year + 1 
    INNER JOIN MyTable t3 ON t2.id = t3.id AND t2.year = t3.year + 1
  );
QUIT;
```

Comment: My data set is in a SAS format, and I would like to do this in SAS. Should I run your code in SAS after changing MyTable with my own dataset? I am totally new to SAS

Comment: I am not familiar with SAS.  All I can say is give it a try.  It shouldn't hurt anything since it is just a simple SELECT statement.

Comment: To run SQL in SAS, wrap it in `PROC SQL; <your sql here> QUIT;`.  Yes, change MyTable to the name of your dataset.  Also, if you don't know how to use SQL solutions, don't add the [tag:sql] tag to your question...

Answer (score 2):

SQL can certainly do this, but SAS can do it a bit more easily (without the join).  This assumes that it is sorted ahead of time by id and year as your example is, without that you need a sort.
This is basically a one pass solution (it only reads the data once here, unless you have more records for one ID than you have buffer memory to hold, but that's unlikely in this example).

This is an example of a double DoW loop, which checks the rows in one ID group first for a condition, then iterates through them a second time to output the qualifying ID rows.

```
data have;
 input id year;
 datalines;
1  2002
1  2003
1  2004
1  2005
1  2006
2  2000
2  2002
2  2003
2  2005
2  2007
2  2009
2  2010
3  2000
3  2002
3  2003
3  2004
3  2007
3  2009
3  2010
;;;;
run;

data want;
 do _n_=1 by 1 until (last.id);
  set have;
  by id;
  yrdif=dif(year);
  if yrdif=1 then cons_yr=cons_yr+1;
  else cons_yr=1;
  max_cons = max(cons_yr,max_cons);
 end;
 do _n_=1 by 1 until (last.id);
  set have;
  by id;
  if max_cons ge 3 then output;
 end;
run;
```